# How to set page template on front using starter content?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I have a page template called template-frontpage.php and I want to show it on front in customizer using new WordPress feature called starter content, following is my code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support( 'starter-content', array(
        'posts' => array(
            'home' => array(
                // Use a page template with the predefined about page
                'template' => 'template-frontpage.php',
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'show_on_front' => 'page',
            'page_on_front' => 'home',
        ),
    ));
});
```

Comment: It is not working, front page is not set to home with page template template-frontpage.php

Comment: The template is not assigneetd, the page is not set for home or both? Please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/256059/edit) and explain the problem you have.

Comment: page is not set and template is also not assigned.

Comment: starter-content only works on fresh installs, have you verified that?. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to a post needs the item symbol within double curly braces:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', function () {
    add_theme_support( 'starter-content', array(
        'posts' => array(
            'home' => array(
                // Use a page template with the predefined about page
                'template' => 'template-frontpage.php',
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'show_on_front' => 'page',
            'page_on_front' => '{{home}}',
        ),
    ));
});
```

**And remember**: currently, starter-content works only on "fresh sites", that is new installs that have not yet had any posts, pages, widgets, or customizer settings updated. This state is indicated in the `fresh_site` option with a value of `1`; if this option is `0`, you can set it back to `1` and starter-content will work in a non-fresh site as well. [It is planned to allow starter content for non-fresh site in future release](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38624) (thanks @weston-ruter).

Comment: Note that at some point core should support applying starter content to non-fresh sites. See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38624

Comment: Good catch, I didn't know.

Comment: Amazing It works, I didn't knew about curly braces.

Comment: It would be so relief if starter content start showing on non-fresh site because right know I'm developing a theme and every time I have to create new WordPress website on localhost for testing :(

Comment: You can set `fresh_site` option to `1` (`update_option( 'fresh_site', 1 )`) and starter content will be workgin again.